# Formtastic nested model form fields (Rails 3)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, formtastic

So here's the scenario:

User:

```
has_one :company
accepts_nested_attributes_for :company
```

Controller:

```
@user = User.new
@user.build_company
```

View:

```
<% semantic_form_for @user, :url => register_path do |form| %>

  <h2>User Information</h2>

  <%= form.inputs %>

  <h2>Company Information</h2>

  <% form.semantic_fields_for :company do |company| %>
    <%= company.inputs %>
  <% end %>

  <%= form.buttons %>

<% end %>
```

After scouring the web, this SEEMS like it should work. However, all I get are the user inputs. The "semantic_fields_for :company" block outputs nothing at all...

Am I missing something here, or is this perhaps a Rails 3 bug to do with Formtastic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use **"<%= %>"** with Rails 3 blocks instead of **"<% %>"**. Thus, the code should be:

```
<%= semantic_form_for @user, :url => register_path do |form| %>

  <h2>User Information</h2>

  <%= form.inputs %>

  <h2>Company Information</h2>

  <%= form.semantic_fields_for :company do |company| %>
    <%= company.inputs %>
  <% end %>

  <%= form.buttons %>

<% end %>
```

Comment: Missing a character... gotta love it :P

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! I spent over an hour looking for this.

Answer (score 0):

as for rails3 new syntax, in your controller you should use

`@user.company.build`

instead of

`@user.build_company`

Comment: tested it on rails3 beta4. it works, this is an example taken from a controller I wrote:

def new
  @realty = Realty.new
  @realty.ownerships.build(:person_id => params[:person_id])

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # new.html.erb
  end
end

the build_* methods was removed for sure.

Comment: It works for you because your @realty has_many ownerships. When it has_one (like in the case of the OP), you need to use @realty.build_ownership